# Модификатор доступа protected в Java

Tags: java

Например, в одном классе у меня есть protected-переменные. Я наследуюсь от этого класса в другом классе. И вот вопрос, какой модификатор доступа будет у этих переменных в подклассе?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такой же как и в классе - родителе - `protected` и вы так же можете использовать их и внутри других классов детей.